# Image or text in between items in QTreeWidget

Tags: qt, pyqt

I was wondering what would be the way to put an image or a little bit of text between items in QTreeWidget. In particular, I would like to have 'OR' and 'AND' show up, to indicate a query structure... is this possible. Any advice would be very much appreciated! Preferably, I was hoping for a pyqt solution.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think to do this would be to insert another `QTreeWidget` item in-between the items at the location you want the text to appear. `QTreeWidgetItem` has some methods like `setDisabled()`, etc. which would allow you to customise the item so it wasn't selectable, had a different colour, or whatever you wanted.

If that isn't good enough, I think you would have to do down the route of changing how the widget is painted, and that will not be easy.